# Drawing on a picture based on coordinates stored in a text file in R

Tags: r, drawing, tiff, trace

I have several TIFF files I have manually drawn shapes on in an external program we use at work, i.e. tracing elements on the picture etc.

That what I drawn is then stored inside a corresponding TXT file as coordinates:

64 255 0 0
3
1457 1051
1685 993
1686 993
0

This is a line (code for line is: 64 255 0 0) with three coordinates (3) which are (1457 1051, 1685 993 and 1686 993). Then the line stop (0).

Question is, if I want to use R (or maybe something else) to import the raw TIFF file and the TXT, how can I get R to draw on the TIFF based on the TXT?

The reason I ask is because I have several thousand TIFFs which must be saved with trancing, and this function is not supported by our in-house program. Thus I must write my own function, with your help!

Thanks!

Comment: You can read in all the text files using scan().  Since they will be in the same format every time, you should be able to save the elements of the text file so that you can easily re-plot. You can iterate each of these text files in a for loop. 

It should be easy to do if you already have the plotting functions done.

Comment: Yes, my real problem is the actual plotting inside R. How do I draw on a picture/plot using coordinates?

Comment: I suppose that is up to you. You can add them as points, and then fit a line or you could draw segments between each coordinate...sort of depends on what you want.

Comment: Add them as points, and then fit a line seams like a good solution. I guess calculating the area of a circle-like object will be easy as well?

Comment: Yep, all doable. So first you need to determine exactly what you want your plot to look like and any parameters you want to save (intercepts, area of your circle, etc) and make this for just one of your text files.

Comment: Ok thanks! I got the basics, Im gonna write the functions now. I will post the final codes as an answer later.

Answer (score 0):

Heres the code for one single picture:

Clean, setup and load

```
    remove(list=ls())
    options(warn=-1)
    library(tiff)
    library(raster)
```

Workdir

```
    dir <- "some/path"
    setwd(dir)
```

Make the new TIFF from the original TIFF + TXT

```
    # Read in original tiff file
    img = readTIFF("Tv2.tif", as.is=FALSE)

    # Make the new tiff
    tiff(file = "test.tiff", width = 512, height = 512, units = "px", res = 100, compression = c("lzw"))

            par(fig = c(0, 1, 0, 1), oma = c(0, 0, 0, 0), mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0), plot.new = TRUE, xpd=TRUE, asp = 1)

            xlim <- c(1, 2048)
            ylim <- c(2048,1)

            plot(1:2,
                 xlim=xlim, 
                 ylim=ylim,
                 asp = 1,
                 xaxs="i", 
                 yaxs="i")

            rasterImage(img, 1, 2048, 2048, 1)

    # List all txt files in dir
    filenames <- list.files(pattern = ".txt", full.names=TRUE)

    # Read in
    txt <- scan(file = filenames[1], what = "numeric", sep = " ")
    txtfix <- as.numeric(txt[2:length(txt)])

    # Search the first multi point object
    mylist <- vector("list", txtfix[1])
    for ( k in 1:length(txtfix) ) {
            if ( txtfix[k] == 64 & txtfix[k+1] == 255 & txtfix[k+2] == 0 & txtfix[k+3] == 0 ) {
                    mylist[[k]] <- txtfix[ c( (k+5):((k+4)+(txtfix[k+4])*2) ) ]
                    elements <- mylist[ !sapply(mylist, is.null) ] # Now I picked out the elemets in the picture                        
            }
    }

    # Getting coordinates for the objects
    xvalues <- NULL
    yvalues <- NULL

    for (i in 1:length(elements)) {
            xvalues[[i]] <- elements[i][[1]][c(T,F)]
            yvalues[[i]] <- elements[i][[1]][c(F,T)]    
    }

    # Drawing using lines()
    for (i in 1:length(xvalues)) {
            lines(c(xvalues[[i]]), c(yvalues[[i]]), type="l", lwd=1, col="pink")      
    }

    dev.off()
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres a version which is looped through all pictures in a folder:

Clean, setup and load

```
    remove(list=ls())
    options(warn=-1)
    library(tiff)
    library(raster)
```

Reading in files

```
    # Set path to txt files for the block
    dir1 <- "path1"
    setwd(dir1)

    # List the txt name
    filenames <- list.files(pattern = ".txt", full.names=TRUE)

    # Make corresponding names to picture name, manualy re-name if bad.
    txtnameslist <- NULL

    for (i in 1:length(filenames)){
            txtnameslist[[i]] <- unique(na.omit(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(unlist(filenames[i]), "[^0-9]+")))))
    }

    txtnames <- NULL
    for (i in 1:length(txtnameslist)) {
            txtnames[[i]] <- paste("Tv", txtnameslist[i][[1]][3], ".tif", sep = "")
    }
```

Make the new TIFF

```
    # Where the original pictures are
    dir2 <- "path2"
    #setwd(dir2)

    # Set folder to save to
    savedir <- "path3"

    for (i in 1:length(txtnames)) {

    # Read in original tiff file
    pic <- paste(dir2, "/", txtnames[[i]], sep="")
    img = readTIFF(pic, as.is=FALSE)

    # Make the new tiff
    file <- paste(savedir, "/", txtnames[[i]], sep="")
    tiff(file = file, width = 512, height = 512, units = "px", res = 100, compression = c("lzw"))

            par(fig = c(0, 1, 0, 1), oma = c(0, 0, 0, 0), mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0), plot.new = TRUE, xpd=TRUE, asp = 1)

            xlim <- c(1, 2048)
            ylim <- c(2048,1)

            plot(1:2,
                 xlim=xlim, 
                 ylim=ylim,
                 asp = 1,
                 xaxs="i", 
                 yaxs="i")

            rasterImage(img, 1, 2048, 2048, 1)

    # List all txt files in dir
    #filenames <- list.files(pattern = ".txt", full.names=TRUE)

    # Read in
    txt <- scan(file = filenames[i], what = "numeric", sep = " ")
    txtfix <- as.numeric(txt[2:length(txt)])

    # Search the first multi point object
    mylist <- vector("list", txtfix[1])
    for ( k in 1:length(txtfix) ) {
            if ( txtfix[k] == 64 & txtfix[k+1] == 255 & txtfix[k+2] == 0 & txtfix[k+3] == 0 ) {
                    mylist[[k]] <- txtfix[ c( (k+5):((k+4)+(txtfix[k+4])*2) ) ]
                    elements <- mylist[ !sapply(mylist, is.null) ] # Now I picked out the elemets in the picture                        
            }
    }

    # Getting coordinates for the objects
    xvalues <- NULL
    yvalues <- NULL

    for (i in 1:length(elements)) {
            xvalues[[i]] <- elements[i][[1]][c(T,F)]
            yvalues[[i]] <- elements[i][[1]][c(F,T)]    
    }

    # Drawing using lines()
    for (i in 1:length(xvalues)) {
            lines(c(xvalues[[i]]), c(yvalues[[i]]), type="l", lwd=1, col="pink")      
    }

    dev.off()

    }
```